# Arduino Is it ok for an interrupt function to call another function?

Tags: c++, arduino, interrupt

I am working on an Arduino project where I receive messages trough I2C communication. I have a couple of routines that the program spends a lot of time in them without returning. Currently, I set an interrupt flag when an interrupt occurs and I basically check in those functions in a couple of places and if an interrupt occurred I return. I was wondering if it is ok for interrupt function to call my entry point function instead.

So this is my current interrupt function

```
void ReceivedI2CMessage(int numBytes)
{
    Serial.print(F("Received message = "));
    while (Wire.available())
    {
        messageFromBigArduino = Wire.read();
    }
    Serial.println(messageFromBigArduino);

    I2CInterrupt = true;
}
```

and In the functions that the program spends most of the time, I had to do this in like a couple of places

```
if(I2CInterrupt) return;
```

Now I was wondering if it is ok to just call my entry point function from within my ReceiveI2CMessage. My main concern is that this might cause a memory leak because I leave the functions that I was executing behind when an interrupt happens and I am going back to the beginning of the program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is okay but not preferred.  It is always safer to do less -- perhaps simply set a flag -- and exit interrupts as fast as possible.  Then take care of the flag/semaphore back in your main loop.  For example:

```
volatile uint8_t i2cmessage = 0;  // must be volatile since altered in an interrupt 

void ReceivedI2CMessage(int numBytes) // not sure what numBytes are used for...
{
    i2cmessage = 1;  // set a flag and get out quickly
}
```

Then in your main loop:

```
loop()
{
    if (i2cmessage == 1) // act on the semaphore
    {
        cli(); // optional but maybe smart to turn off interrupts while big message traffic going through...
        i2cmessage = 0; // reset until next interrupt
        while (Wire.available())
        {
            messageFromBigArduino = Wire.read();
            // do something with bytes read
        }
        Serial.println(messageFromBigArduino);
        sei(); // restore interrupts if turned off earlier
    }
}
```

This achieves the goal of the interrupt, which is ideally to set a semaphore to be acted on quickly in the main loop.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense for the interrupt part, but my main problem is that my program visits the main loop once in every 30 seconds or so because it is busy in 2 other functions. Is there an easy way to return from those functions when an interrupt occurs without spreading if(i2cmessage == 1) all over the place?

Comment: It is not typical in microcontroller designs to only visit the main loop every 30 seconds.  This is usually a sign that the design could be improved.  But the good news is, if you're just worried about a memory leak, even a small leak will become apparent pretty soon, as the SRAM on these devices is so small.  The bad news is if you have a leak, you'll need to take a hard look at your design anyway.  I recommend quick returns from all functions and especially from interrupts.